# Deleting patterned text from an html using python

Tags: python, html, regex

I tried to use python to write a script, deleting a certain patterned text within an html. However, my code doesn't seem to work.. Would you help me check where went wrong?

```
import os, re

cwd = os.getcwd()
print ('Now you are at this directory: \n' + cwd)

# find files that have an extension with HTML
Files = os.listdir(cwd)
print Files

def func(file):
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.html'):
            for line in open(file):
                re.sub(r'<strong>.*?<\/strong>', '', line)
                # I feel the above line has some problems
func(file)
```

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to escape / in your re. `\/` is in fact just an ordinary `/`. See the introduction of [the re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for a complete reference.

Your regex should be: `r'<strong>.*?</strong>'`

It is however not recommended to parse html with regexes. See [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for that!

```
line = '<p>some text, <strong>SOME STRONG TEXT </strong> and again <strong>STONG TEXT</strong></p>'
re.sub(r'<strong>.*?<\/strong>', '', line)
#'<p>some text,  and again </p>'
```

Comment: Thank you Thierry, I'll definitely check out beautifulsoup! For the regular expression, I tried both patterns, but neither of them work...If you use my original script and try to print out the matched texts, they are actually correct. I'm just not sure which part is wrong in the code that prevents me from replacing the matched strings...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

```
import os, re

cwd = os.getcwd()
print ('Now you are at this directory: \n' + cwd)

# find files that have an extension with HTML
Files = os.listdir(cwd)

def func(file):
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.html'):
                f = open(file, "r+")
                text  = re.sub(r'\<strong\>.*\<\/strong\>',"",f.read())
                f.close()
                f = open(file, "w")
                f.write(text)
                f.close()
func(file)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!! In my case, I may need to try further - see if beautiful soup would help more. :)